# How can I recover my pictures from Vaulty Stocks

Tags: data-recovery

I've lost my phone. Is there any way of getting back my files and pictures which were saved in [Vaulty Stocks](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.theronrogers.vaultypro)?

Answer (score 1):

I realize that this doesn't directly answer your question since it appears you don't have a backup, however I have used [Vaulty](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.theronrogers.vaultyfree), which looks like the free version of the same app by the same company, so I am assuming the method used to hide your files is the same.

If you are able to find your `.vdata` files you can easily convert them all back into regular files by the command line without any sort of password/pin.

Make a backup (just in case) and then put all your `.vdata` files in the same directory and execute:

```
find . -type f -name "*.vdata" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/\x6F\x62\x73\x63\x75\x72\x65\x64//'
```

Poof. There are all your files. This definitely works for Linux, but I'm not sure about Mac. If someone can confirm this for Mac feel free to update this answer or comment and I'll do it myself.

Unfortunately (if you are actually interested in security) Vaulty DOES NOT secure your files at all! If you need real security, you need an app that actually encrypts your files with something like AES encryption. However if you lose your password there, you're sweet out of luck. That's a good thing. Just make sure you don't forget your password.

Comment: could you please be more specific? How exactly do I execute that command? Does it work for Windows 7?

Comment: No, Windows doesn't have the `find`, `xargs`, and `sed` utilities you need. You can get them by installing Cygwin, but that's quite involved so you should ask a local friend to walk you through it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have lost your phone and do not have a backup of the Vaulty Stocks data then there is no way to recover it. If you have a backup you may be able to install the app on another device and access the data by entering the password you used originally.